# Supervisor Authentication to Allow an Action in Grails with Spring Security Plugin

Tags: spring, authentication, grails, spring-security, authorization

How can I perform a strategy to make supervisor authentication with Grails and Spring Security Plugin?

Let's see this scenario:

An user is working on fill some data into an income report. For the report to be submitted, the approval of a supervisor is required. The user can call the supervisor to your workstation to perform the insertion of their credentials only to witness that action.

It's possible with Spring Security or I'll have to implement that feature?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's the 'Switch User' feature, described in the docs here: https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/switchUser.html

Comment: Burt! You are awesome. Sometimes we use the wrong search terms and don't see the answer in front of us. That's all I need. But, how can I take this 'su' user in service context for audit reasons?

Comment: You can get the original username with `SpringSecurityUtils.getSwitchedUserOriginalUsername()` or the `<sec:switchedUserOriginalUsername/>` tag

Comment: Glad to help; feel free to accept this as the answer ;)